# Plotting a sum as a function of its upper bound

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning, summation

Apologies if this is easy to find in the documentation, but is there a quick way of doing the following up to any given 'n'?

```
a=
Im[n^ZetaZero[1]] + Re[n^ZetaZero[1]] + Im[n^ZetaZero[2]] + Re[n^ZetaZero[2]] + 
Im[n^ZetaZero[3]] + Re[n^ZetaZero[3]] + Im[n^ZetaZero[4]] + Re[n^ZetaZero[4]] + 
Im[n^ZetaZero[5]] + ... ;

Plot[{If[a >= 0, (a^2)/n, -(a^2)/n]}, {n, 0, 30}]
```

For clarity, I include the plot for `n` up to `30`, for `ZetaZero` up to `100`:

[image]

Comment: With `n` you're not referring to the `n` you use in the plot index specification, right? Do you mean something like this `Plot[Sum[Im[n^ZetaZero[i]] + Re[n^ZetaZero[i]], {i, 5}], {n, 0, 20}]`? I wonder what the 2 variables of your title stand for...

Comment: Yes - I would like to plot for `n^Re[ZetaZero[x]] + n^Im[ZetaZero[x]]` up to some `x` for for some range of `n`.

Comment: It seems that my code suggestion above does what you want then, or not?

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries, yes - many thanks, though it seems to take a lot longer to computer than if written out 'longhand'. I am using the following: `a = Sum[Im[n^ZetaZero[i]] + Re[n^ZetaZero[i]], {i, 100}];`
`Plot[{If[a >= 0, (a^2)/n, -(a^2)/n]}, {n, 0, 30}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I sure there are many more.

```
a[k_, n_] := Sum[Re[n^#] + Im[n^#] &[ZetaZero[i] // N], {i, k}]
Plot[With[{a = a[100, n]}, Sign[a] a^2/n], {n, 0, 30}]
```

[image: plot.png]

Comment: thank you - seems a little quicker, though haven't tested the timing yet! Again - many thanks :)